# Identify original title of a 90's TV show featuring Dinosaurs

Tags: story-identification, animated-series

I used to watch a cartoon TV show in mid-90s India which had Dinosaurs (produced possibly in the aftermath of Jurassic Park's success). I don't remember more details (like plot), but I have its intro:

The audio is in Hindi (an Indian language), but human characters don't seem Indian. They look similar to that from [Dungeons & Dragons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dungeons_%26_Dragons_(TV_series)) TV show. So, this is likely an American or Japanese cartoon dubbed in Hindi.

Can you please identify the original title of the TV show?

Comment: The title is literally there at 1:12 in your video clip.

Comment: @JamesK Oh. I didn't watch that. Lack of patience to watch kid stuff. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that might be [Denver the last dinosaur.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denver,_the_Last_Dinosaur)

From Wikipedia:

> The show revolves around the adventures of Denver, the eponymous last dinosaur, who was released from his egg by a group of California teens: Jeremy, Mario, Shades, Wally, and Casey, along with tag-along older sister, Heather. The kids taught Denver the finer points of skateboarding and other pastimes while protecting him from rock concert promoter Morton Fizzback who wanted to use the dinosaur to make money.

This is the intro in english.